# i can not stop .wav file from playing in java frame

Tags: java

I have GUI java frame with two buttons: start button and stop button.
The start button, supposedly when pressed the .wav sound file continuously plays, and the stop button supposedly stops playing the .wav sound file. When I press the start button, the start playing works correctly,however, the stop button refuses to work or has no effect in stopping the .wav file from playing. I have tried many things as you will see in my code. Any help will be appreciated.
**FIXED FROM HERE UP**

```
  package newframe;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.*; 
  import static java.time.Clock.system;
  import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
  import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
  import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
  import java.awt.*;
  import javax.swing.*;

  /**  *  
       * @author gamalt  
       */
  public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {
    /**
      * Creates new form NewJFrame
      */
    Clip clip;
    volatile int x=5;
    static int xx=0;
    int y=200;
    public Thread thread= null;
    public NewJFrame() {
      initComponents();
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      thread = new Thread(this,"gamal");
    }

    public void run(){
      System.out.println("you are in run");
      x=20;
    }

    /**
      * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
      * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
      * regenerated by the Form Editor.
    */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
      jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
      START = new javax.swing.JButton();
      STOP = new javax.swing.JButton();
      jColorChooser1 = new javax.swing.JColorChooser();

      jButton1.setText("jButton1");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      START.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 153));
      START.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
      START.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 51, 51));
      START.setText("START");
      START.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          STARTActionPerformed(evt);
        }
      });

      STOP.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
      STOP.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
      STOP.setText("STOP");
      STOP.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          STOPActionPerformed(evt);
        }
      });

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
      getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout
          .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
          .addGroup(
            layout
              .createSequentialGroup()
              .addComponent(
                jColorChooser1,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                0,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
              .addGap(108, 108, 108)
              .addComponent(
                STOP, 
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                98,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
              .addPreferredGap(
                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
                216,
                Short.MAX_VALUE)
              .addComponent(
                START, 
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                117,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
              .addGap(82, 82, 82))
      );
      layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout
          .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
          .addGroup(
            layout
              .createSequentialGroup()
              .addContainerGap()
              .addGroup(
                layout
                  .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                  .addComponent(
                    jColorChooser1,
                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                  .addGroup(
                    layout
                      .createSequentialGroup()
                      .addGap(93, 93, 93)
                      .addGroup(
                        layout
                          .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                          .addComponent(
                            START,
                            javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                            61,
                            javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                          .addComponent(
                            STOP,
                            javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                            61,
                            javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))).addContainerGap(78, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


// FIXED FROM HERE DOWN!!!!
private void STARTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    try {
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            //AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("src/myrecord3.wav"));  
            // AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(NewJFrame.class.getResourceAsStream("myrecord3.wav"));
            BufferedInputStream myStream = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("myrecord3.wav"));
            // just addes
            AudioInputStream audio2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(myStream); //just added
            //AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("src/myrecord3.wav"));
            // clip.open(inputStream);
            clip.open(audio2);
            xx=5;
            // clip.start(); 
            // clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            System.out.println("hi");
            // clip.drain();
            while(xx == 5){
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.loop(0);
            clip.start();
            // System.out.println("yes againg");
            // while(clip.isActive())
            // x=y;
            Thread.sleep(10000);}
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    private void STOPActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here
        xx=200;            //stop the thread
        // System.exit(0);
        // Thread.yield();
        //thread.start();
        if(clip == null)
        System.out.println("clip is null");
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            System.out.println("stop");
            clip.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("something is wrong");
        }
    }                                    

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
        * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
        */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>


        catch(Exception e) {}
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton START;
    private javax.swing.JButton STOP;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JColorChooser jColorChooser1;
    // End of variables declaration                    
}
```

Comment: Beyond that: import the classes you are using, instead of always using fully qualified names. And learn about Java naming conventions. All upper case is reserved for constants for example!

Comment: Even with the partial reformatting I did, it still is barely human readable. Use your imports. Itll save a lot of headaches and typing. Wouldn't have to break the () like I had to.

Comment: guys I managed to clean up about bottom 100 lines, remove `>` in front of lines and also space in front of intro paragraph. I got to get advil or ibroprofen after this. Seriously this code gives me headaches.

Comment: But you'll never succeed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uMX_QHQqEU, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyCfp_Zz5Ek, :-)